# Parameter passed from Angular to C# endpoint is not expected type

Tags: c#, angular, post

I am trying to pass a parameter via POST from an Angular client to a c# backend. I cant figure out why the first approach fails when the second one works. In both cases isnt the result passed to c# converted back into its type?

ANGULAR

```
passwordResetRequest(email: string): Observable<string> {
    console.log('auth svc: ' + email)
    return this.http.post<string>("api/auth/forgotPassword", {email:email} ).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('error sending pwd reset request','error receiving response'))
    );
}
```

C# endpoint FAILS

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("forgotPassword")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword(JsonResult r){}//500 server error

//FAILS also
public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword([FromBody] string r){}//r=null
```

C# endpoint WORKS

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("forgotPassword")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword([FromBody] MyClass r)

public class MyClass
{
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can remember, ASP.NET WebAPI can't handle `text/plain` media type, so if you send only the string your endpoint get an empty string, you can try to set other Content-Type header on the request, or, if you want to add support to `text/plain` content type you can follow [this tutorial.](https://andydote.co.uk/2015/09/21/webapi-post-plaintext/)

```
public class PlainTextMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public PlainTextMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        try
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                readStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
                source.SetResult(text);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            source.SetException(e);
        }
        return source.Task;
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, System.Net.TransportContext transportContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value.ToString());
        return writeStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string);
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string);
    }
}
```

This can then be added to the config.Formatters collection:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration http)
  {
    http.Formatters.Add(new PlainTextMediaTypeFormatter());
  }
}
```